# (#100) achievement URL is not properly formatted

Tags: facebook, achievements

I got an error from Facebook while I registered an achievement in it. I called:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[APP_ID]/achievements?achievement=[url]&access_token=[accessToken]&display_order=1
```

Error message:

> (#100) achievement URL is not properly formatted

How do I fix it?

Comment: Probably by formatting your URL properly. (urlencode)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `og:url` you specified in the target achievement URL is not proper. Verify your target achievement URL in the [Debugger Tool](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug).